# How to access to some project which is referred to from another project?

Tags: c#, project-reference, class-reference

**Project 1**

-- *Class X*

**Project 2**
References **Project 1**

Project 3
* References **Project 2**
* Needs *ClassX* ?

I want to access *ClassX* from Project 3 - is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Reference Project 1 in Project 3. Whatever you do don't reference Project 1 from Project 2 and Project 2 from Project 1 (or some other circular reference dependency) - in such cases you need a third common project which contains the required shared types.

Comment: No i dont reference Project 1 from Project 2 and Project 2 from Project 1. I just want to know is there anyway to create new Class X in Project 3 without using common project :D

Comment: Re-read my comment. The part you responded to was additional advice for the future since you said you're a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

[image]

In this example, `Project3` is the main project while `Project1` and `Project2` are class library projects.

Since `Project2` refers to `Project1`. `Project3` just needs to refer to `Project2`. Then you can access all of class libraries from `Project1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add reference of project1 in project3

[image]